# how can i put css with colspan = any odd number?

Tags: css

how can i put css with colspan = any odd number ?

```
.rms_home_table td.borderNone[colspan="2"] {
    background-image: url(mid_line.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100px 30px;
}

what I required this to be done 

.rms_home_table td.borderNone[colspan="any odd number"]
```

Comment: Why don't you make use of a class instead of trying to do something like that?

Answer (score -1):

Simple CSS would be

```
tr:nth-child(even) {

}
```